# update query params checkbox filter angular 4

Tags: angular

Select on checkbox url need to update like this http://localhost:4200/en/offers?location=east&location=west using angular 4.

I am use this for single value only update:

```
this.router.navigate([], { relativeTo: this.route, queryParams: { location: 'ss', } });
```

My code:

```
onLocationChange() {

    const filteredData = [];
    const filteredLocationName = [];
    let lastItem;
    let allSameResult = true;
    this.locationGrp.value.location.map((s, i) => {
        if (typeof lastItem !== "undefined" && lastItem !== s) {
            allSameResult = false;
        }
        if (s) {
            filteredData.push(this.coordinates[i].id);
            filteredLocationName.push(this.coordinates[i].languages[this.currentLang].name);
        }
        lastItem = s;
    });
    if (!allSameResult) {
        this.locationGrp.get('all').enable();
        this.locationGrp.get('all').patchValue(false);
        // if all true or all false no need to update filter
        this.locationFilterData = filteredData;
        this.lastLocationFilterData = filteredData;
        this.locationFilterSlug = filteredLocationName;
        this.router.navigate([], {
            relativeTo: this.route,
            queryParams: {
                location: 'ss',
            }
        });
    } else {
        this.locationGrp.get('all').patchValue(true);
        this.locationFilterData = [];
        this.lastLocationFilterData = [];
        this.locationFilterSlug = [];
    }
    this.locationFilterUpdate = !this.locationFilterUpdate;
    // for first tim change reverse
    if (!this.allLocationInitial) {
        if (!allSameResult) {
            this.allLocationFilter = false;
            /* this.allLocationFilterDisable = false;*/
        } else {
            this.allLocationFilter = true;
        }
    } else {
        this.allLocationFilter = true;
        this.allLocationInitial = false;
    }


}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i want to pass mutiple query parms based on filter..